# Permutation test and p-value

Tags: statistics, permutations, hypothesis-testing

I construct a permutation test in order to see If two samples come from the same distribution or not. I have two vectors $x, y$ that hold values of sampled values from two populations and the test statistics $mean(x)-mean(y)$.  I am given a p-value and the test and I need to decide whether to reject or accept $H_0$.  How can I use p value to make a decision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decision: Reject $H_0$ if p-value is less than the given level of significance otherwise accept $H_0$.